# How to add some java code to be processed instead of just a rule defined in xml in tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

Tags: tomcat, tomcat6, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

In tuckey-urlrewrite-filter.

How to add some java code to be processed instead of just a rule defined in xml

I need to capture a SOAP message and modify it before it will go to futher processing.
Its why I need to write some Java code.

Comment: I've completely lost you..Can you provide some more info?

Comment: What exactly do you want to change?

Comment: There is an application App A that sends request to Web Service present on Tomcat. I need to capture this request and modify it. I need to see the details of a request from Java level to be able to modify it and to send it further for Web Service to prcoess it.

Comment: So do you want to change soap message itself, not url?

Comment: thats right - I think I will use custom filter to do the thing -

Comment: http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/what-is-a-filter-and-how-do-i-use-it.html?page=1